# How to count the field name start with same prefix when submit the form?

Tags: php, laravel, form-submit

I need to count the field which starts with the same prefix value in PHP laravel before submitting.
Below is the Laravel response and here I need to count the field name which starts with "of_".

```
{
    "_token": "c3wPhNtM86QujtsugZaZTonLUnWJBWjyyRMhorsd",
    "name": null,
    "type": null,
    "no_of_guest": "200",
    "time": "Breakfast",
    "price": null,
    "service_charge": null,
    "of_1": [
        "1",
        "6"
    ],
    "of_2": [
        "8",
        "11"
    ],
    "of_3": [
        "2",
        "12"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count how many fields named `of_*`  or count the integers inside of them? or sum everything?

Answer (score 2):

Something like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8456fb4e41ad43e1bf0a109cb26a241e80fe380e) should help you.

```
<?php
$json = '{"_token":"c3wPhNtM86QujtsugZaZTonLUnWJBWjyyRMhorsd","name":null,"type":null,"no_of_guest":"200","time":"Breakfast","price":null,"service_charge":null,"of_1":["1","6"],"of_2":["8","11"],"of_3":["2","12"]}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'of_') === 0) {
       echo print_r($value);
    }
}
```